# How to make an iframe take up all remaining room

Tags: html, css, iframe, height

I have the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="res/favicon.ico" />
<title>My website</title>

<style type="text/css">
    .wrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
    text-align:center;
}

#header, #footer {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:999999;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
      <div class="wrap">
           <div class="logo">
                <h1>Header</h1>
           </div>
           <div>Menu goes here</div>
      </div>
 </div>

 <iframe src="http://www.cnn.com"></iframe>

  <div id="footer">
      <div class="wrap">
           <h2>Footer</h2>
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I setup the iframe so that it'll take all the remaining width and height between the header and the footer?

Comment: Look at my answer, I needed to use some javascript but it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solved it, needed some javascript :)**

**Live example:**
<s>http://simplestudio.rs/yard/framed/framed.html</s> (offline)

**CODE:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="res/favicon.ico" />
<title>My website</title>

<style type="text/css">

#framed {

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   

}

.wrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
    text-align:center;
}

#header, #footer {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:999999;
}
</style>

    <script>

        var resize = setInterval(function(){chng_iframe_height('framed','header','footer')},500);

        function chng_iframe_height(ifrid,hid,fid) {

            var eheight = window.innerHeight;
            var ifrobj = document.getElementById(ifrid); 
            var header = document.getElementById(hid); 
            var footer = document.getElementById(fid); 
            var header_height = getComputedStyle(header).height;
            var footer_height = getComputedStyle(footer).height;

            var reserved_height = parseInt(header_height) + parseInt(footer_height);

            ifrobj.style.height = eheight - reserved_height +"px";     

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="chng_iframe_height('framed','header','footer');">
  <div id="header">
      <div class="wrap">
           <div class="logo">
                <h1>Header</h1>
           </div>
           <div>Menu goes here</div>
      </div>
 </div>

 <iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" id="framed"></iframe>

  <div id="footer">
      <div class="wrap">
           <h2>Footer</h2>
      </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basicaly, I compute header and Footer rendered height, get window.innerHeight and from that numbers I know how much px is there left between header in footer so I assign that value to iframe and whoila it works...

Also I have set setinterval to call that function every half second so if you resize window it will almost immediately update iframe height...

Comment: It works good :)
I wonder though, why do you use the setInterval?

Comment: Because if you call chng_iframe_height() only on body onload you will only have 1 height of iframe that fits that particular moment depending on window size. So If you change for some reason window size your iframe height will remain as it was so your design will break. Am I clear enough?

Comment: Ah, now I get it :)
Will it simplify the code if I'd say I'm not concerned about resizing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a class to your iframe or style it on the spot like this:

```
<iframe style="height:100%; width:100%;" src="http://www.cnn.com"></iframe>
```

Try this also:

```
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.cnn.com"></iframe>
```

Also don't forget to remove the padding/margin on the body tag so the header and footer go all the way:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

EDIT:

If this does not work you'll have to add fixed width and height.

Comment: Trying the two methods led to the same result: The element does spread to the entire width, but only to 154px height.

I did not see why I should add the body css code, Isn't it done by default?

Comment: Well you could try and test that, just put some div to 100% width and see to where it goes. About the iframe: try changing the height rule in the first example into min-height. You should experiment with the `min-height` and `position` css rules. Google them.

Answer (score 0):

I made used of .css() and $(window).height() When you use $(window).height() make sure you have doctype as html

```
<script>
      var resize = setInterval(function(){chng_iframe_height('framed','header','footer')},500);

        function chng_iframe_height(ifrid,hid,fid) {

            var eheight = $(window).height();
            var ifrobj = document.getElementById(ifrid); 
            var header_height = $("#" + hid).css("height"); // getComputedStyle(header).height;
            var footer_height = $("#" + fid).css("height"); 

            var reserved_height = parseInt(header_height) + parseInt(footer_height);

            ifrobj.style.height = eheight - reserved_height +"px";     

        }
    </script>
```